# Vue вычисляемое значение пустое при рендере шаблона компонента

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vue.js

Есть компонент vue, в нем в mounted через api битрикса получаю список товаров, затем в шаблоне через директиву v-for хочу вывести их, но тут столкнулся с проблемой, я записываю полученные через api данные в вычисляемое значение products, но при рендере оно пустое и ничего не выводит в шаблоне, а если сделать console.log в mounted, то полученные данные видны.
Код компонента:

```js
var Products = Vue.component('products', {
    data: function () {
         return {
            products: '',
            deal_id: '',
            inited: false,
         }
    },
     methods: {
        create(){
            
        },
     },
     mounted: function(){
        BX24.init( () => {
            this.deal_id = BX24.placement.info()
            BX24.callMethod(
                "crm.deal.productrows.get",
                { id: this.deal_id.options.ID },
                function(result)
                {
                    if(result.error())
                        console.error(result.error());
                    else
                        this.products = JSON.stringify(result.data())
                        this.inited = true
                }
            );
        })
    },
     template: '<div class="container">\n' +
     '    <div class="ontime">\n' +
     '      <h1 v-on:click="test">Товары</h1>\n' +
         '<div id="test">{{ products }}</div>' +
         '<div v-for="(item, i) in products" class="input-group">\n' +
         '          <div class="label">\n' +
         '            <label for="address-input">{{ item.PRODUCT_NAME }}</label>\n' +
         '          </div>\n' +
         '       <input style="width: 200px; margin-right: 10px;" placeholder="Количество" type="text" class="select-i"><button class="btn btn-primary createProd" v-on:click="create">button</button>\n' +
         '      </div>\n'+
     '       <div></div>\n' +
     '      </div>\n' +
     '    </div>\n' +
     '</div>'
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.js"></script>
```

В чем косяк? Версия vue 2.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Репу в минус кинули, ну ок знатоки, нашел решение сам, из-за функций битрикса с колбеками this выполняется в конетексте другого объекта, решается так :

```js
const self = this
```